# change source between elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im looking for a way to replace the link inside the target element with the link from the source element. I know how to do this when you match the links - but how do I do this dynamically when I don't know what the links will be by using the link classes?

```
<a class="target"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/remote/i3-ytimg-com/184998082.jpg" height="280" width="280" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></a>

<a class="source"><img src="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/remote/i3-ytimg-com/100.jpg" height="280" width="280" style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"></a>
```

Comment: maybe you should assign some ID to anchors

Comment: Why? Cant I use the different classes on the element? Use replaceWith or similar by targeting the classes to change the src link?

Comment: I see you found a solution :) did you try it? what's the result? please, share your tries

Comment: No I didn't find a solution. everything i find depends of me knowing the link before - where I want to do this dynamically.

Comment: if you can set an unique ID to an html element, you can't find it without any problem everytime everywhere, even dinamically. Please, can you share the code you are using in "dinamically" scenario?

Comment: All i want is to switch the attribute values based on the link classes above - and I want to do this dynamically regardless of how the links are constructed. I haven't found a solution for this - thus no code to share.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, please try it, so eventually I can fix the code

```
$(".target")
    .children("img")
        .attr("src",
            $(".source").children("img").attr("src")
        )
```